# Highcharts does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I'm trying to do the most basic example from this site:
http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/your-first-chart

But it doesn't seem to work. Here's the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container'
            },

            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime'
            },

            series: [{
                data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
                pointStart: Date.UTC(2012, 0, 1),
                pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
            }]
        });

        $('#container').highcharts(options);
    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *Why* doesn't it work? What's happening? What's the error? (Likely that something is undefined, since you've included jQuery incorrectly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add `</script>` closing tag.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
     chart: {
       renderTo: 'container'
     },
     xAxis: {
       type: 'datetime'
     },
     series: [{
       data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
       pointStart: Date.UTC(2012, 0, 1),
       pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
     }]
   });
   $('#container').highcharts(options);
 });
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
```

Comment: I should have changed my IDE for writing javascript. Geany is not the best choice apparently. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

**You are missing the closing `</script>` tag.**

You can recognize some kind of error even in the code snippet itself as there is a colur change in one of the `<script>` tag.

All the other code is working fine.

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yuLf6hhg/)